# data.corr() not displaying some of the correlations for variables. instead it just displays white tiles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I am trying to show the correlation between variables on my dataset. Some of the variables correlations are presented but others are not. I am using a code I found online and wondering how can I alter it to make it show the correlation between all my variables?

```
data = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv', index_col = 0)
corr = data.corr()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(corr,cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ticks = np.arange(0,len(data.columns),1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(data.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(data.columns)
plt.show()
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHgEy.png)

[expecting an output more like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lErZK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, what if you replace `ax.set_xticklabels(data.columns)` by `ax.set_xticklabels(['sex', 'bmi', 'children'])` and `ax.set_yticklabels(data.columns)` by `ax.set_yticklabels(['sex', 'bmi', 'children'])`

Comment: I tried replacing them to include all the variables `ax.set_xticklabels(['sex', 'bmi', 'children', 'smoker', 'region', 'charges'])
ax.set_yticklabels(['sex', 'bmi', 'children', 'smoker', 'region', 'charges'])` but still the same output rip